# DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT ORACLE 11g 5 jobs submitted together but 1st job takes unusually longer than rest of 4 jobs although total records processed are same

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, job-queue, dbms-job

I am submitting 5 jobs using below code but 1 st jobs takes around an hour more than rest of 4 jobs although number of records processed are same.

```
loop
  V_SEQID := V_SEQID + 1;
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(jobNUMBER, 'package_name.'||v_process||'('||l_processid||','''||i_currentrundate||''','''||l_userid||''','''||automanualflag||''','''||l_machinename||''','||i_seqid||','||v_seqid||','||v_min||','||v_sequenceidto||','||v_Batchno||','||G_batch_seq_no||','''||l_tab_delimiter||''');',
                  SYSDATE,
                  NULL,
                  FALSE);
end loop;
```

Comment: The first step is to convert from DBMS_JOB to DBMS_SCHEDULER.  With DBMS_SCHEDULER you will have much more debugging information, like DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.  It's possible that Oracle limits the number of jobs run, but you need a history table to know which job ran when.

Comment: Thanks @JonHeller. We will definitely move to DBMS_SCHEDULER.I am able to identify the actual issue. We are dividing the job on the basis of sequential record due to which load is not getting divided equally as stating records have to do more processing as compared to latter records(newer records). Hence now I have divided the records on mix basis using mod fucntion.